# Global service objects in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a service file that processes data and stores it in private fields. Many queries are executed, hence I'd like to instantiate the service file only once and access data from the fields when necessary in later stages of the request's lifecycle.

I've tried registering the service file in Laravel's service provider using the following snippet, but it did not seem to work as I expected.

```php
$this->app->singleton('App\Services\UserService', function ($app) {
    return new App\Services\UserService();
});
```

In my case, the first time I called the service methods was in my middleware class. The particular methods I called should've set many private fields in place which I could later use. Service file was loaded in using the "injection" method.

```php
public function __construct(UserService $user_service) {
    $this->user_service = $user_service;
}
```

However, once the request finally proceeded to the controller method, the fields in the service object had been nulled and I had to call the "heavy" methods once again.

Within the the controller constructor method, I resolved the service file using the `resolve()` helper method, however I don't think that would've made a difference.

Is there something I've missed or misunderstood?

Any help or pointers are appriciated!

Comment: This looks correct. Could you show the middleware and controller?

Comment: The controller is instantiated before the middleware  are run. Is it possible you depend on for example the authenticated user to do the expensive processing and queries to fill the `UserService`? Try to inject the `UserService` in your controller methods instead of the constructor.

Comment: Laravel service providers can inject dependencies in many places, controllers constructor, controllers methods, events constructor, jobs handle methods,... . Your code seems to be fine for getting data on places where automatic injection is required. But take a look at [here][1]. This real time facades may make more sense for your usage.


  [1]: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/facades#real-time-facades

Comment: @AlexBouma Indeed, I rely on the authenticated user. However, user is set by using a specific setter method after service is resolved. In the controller, I moved the injection to one of the controller methods, thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately, it seems to make no difference.

Comment: In that case, not knowing more on how the "expensive" operation is triggered (or when) and what/when the authenticated user has a role I would not have more things to try. Try and debug the flow and how many times things are called and from where to see if the expensive operation is maybe triggered twice or overwritten by setting the user or triggered before all information required is available.